# Работа return в рекурсивной функции php

Tags: php

Доброго времени суток.
Есть код. Не важна его практическая ценность, интересует как это работает.

```
<?php

    $arr = array(
            0=>'Aaa',
            1=>'Bbb',
            2=>'Ccc'
        );

    function getArr($arr){

        static $exit_arr = array();

        if((is_array($arr)) && (!empty($arr))){

            for($i=0; $i<count($arr); $i++){

                $exit_arr[] = $arr[$i];

                unset($arr[count($arr)-1]);

                getArr($arr);
            }
        }
        else{
            return $exit_arr;
        }
    }

    print_r(getArr($arr));
```

Если оставить так, то return ничего не возвращает.
Если же убрать блок else и оставить return вне его, то
return возвращает.

Почему так происходит?
Заранее благодарю за ответ.

Comment: потому что с `else` существует путь в логике (path of execution), не вызывaющий `return`. Добавьте `return` перед `getArr($arr);` внутри `if`.

Comment: так в блоке `if` `return`-а нет, как он возвращать что будет, если до `else` не доходит?

Comment: @Igor если перед `getArr` добавить, то вообще все сломается, ибо от цикла будет происходить только одна итерация.

Comment: "существует путь в логике (path of execution)", а где об этом почитать можно?

Answer (score 1):

> Почему так происходит?

Так происходит потому, что в самом первом вызове функции вы передаёте в неё НЕпустой массив. В итоге условие внутри функции будет истинным и управление провалится внутрь `if`'а. С этого момента уже не имеет значения, что произойдёт дальше и какая там рекурсия. Конструкция `return` для первого вызова снаружи - недостижима.

Это можно увидеть, если добавить немного отладки, которая покажет стек вызовов. Будет ясно в каком месте какое значение у входных аргументов и какое у статичного массива с результатом внутри функции. Да, результат будет накапливаться и он даже вернётся с помощью `return` наружу. Но по стеку вызовов он вернётся одному из рекурсивных вызовов, а не тому, что вы делаете снаружи функции в самом начале.

```
function getArr(array $in, int $level = 0)
{
    static $out = [];

    $indent = str_repeat("  ", $level);
    echo "{$indent}" .
        "getArr([" . implode(", ", $in) . "], {$level})\t" .
        "out = [" . implode(", ", $out) . "]\n";

    if (!empty($in)) {
        for ($i = 0; $i < count($in); $i++) {
            $out[] = $in[$i];
            unset($in[count($in) - 1]);
            getArr($in, $level + 1);
        }
    }
    return $out;
}

echo "[" . implode(", ", getArr(['a', 'b', 'c'])) . "]\n";
```

Это почти целиком ваш оригинальный код с небольшими правками для отладки. `Output` получается такой:

```
getArr([a, b, c], 0) out = []
  getArr([a, b], 1)  out = [a]
    getArr([a], 2)   out = [a, a]
      getArr([], 3)  out = [a, a, a]
  getArr([a], 1)     out = [a, a, a, b]
    getArr([], 2)    out = [a, a, a, b, a]
[a, a, a, b, a]
```

В самой первой строчке - ваш внешний первый вызов функции. Именно от него вы ожидаете возврата значения. Но, как видите, массив не пустой и функция вместо возврата накопившегося результата просто в цикле вызывает саму себя ещё дважды. А эти вызовы снова и снова.

Самые глубокие вызовы выполняются с пустым массивом на входе `getArr([], ..` - вот они то как раз и выполнят `return` внутри `else`. Но вернут своё значение своим родителям уровнем выше, а те результат не принимают вовсе.

Answer (score -2):

```
if(УСЛОВИЕ)
{
инструкция, которая сработает в случае когда (УСЛОВИЕ) == true;
}
else
{
инструкция, которая сработает только в случае если (УСЛОВИЕ) == false
}
```

В вашем случае происходит: if соответствует условиям и выполняет инструкции, но else не срабатывает потому что уже сработал if. Если убрать else и оставить return, то в блоке if выполнится инструкция присвоение значения переменной ($exit_arr[] = $arr[$i]) и в return попадает уже переменная с новым значением.